# MYSQL Error 1060 Duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT SUM(T.KDV) AS TOTALKDV
FROM   (SELECT *
    FROM pharmana_urun_db.general_Table, pharmana_Hareket_db.general_Table
    WHERE pharmana_urun_db.general_Table.Barkod = pharmana_Hareket_db.general_Table.Barkod AND  pharmana_Hareket_db.general_Table.EczaneID = '".$pharmacy_id"') AS T
GROUP BY T.Kategori
```

> ## 1060 - Duplicate column name 'Barkod',

how can I avoid this?

Comment: Start using modern explizit join syntax

Comment: Because you have multiple fields called Barkod. You need to be explicit instead of the `SELECT * FROM` and rename/alias any columns that have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

`(SELECT *
    FROM pharmana_urun_db.general_Table, pharmana_Hareket_db.general_Table`

This selects two columns with the same name `Barkod`

You need to use the explicit join syntax as Jens suggested

Nice explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  Don't use subqueries unnecessarily.

You should write this query as:

```
SELECT SUM(T.KDV) AS TOTALKDV
FROM pharmana_urun_db.general_Table gt1 JOIN
     pharmana_Hareket_db.general_Table gt2
     USING (Barkod)
WHERE gt2.EczaneID = '".$pharmacy_id"'
GROUP BY Kategori;
```

You should also learn to use parameters to pass values into SQL queries, rather than munging query strings.  I also suspect that you should be including `Kategori` in the `SELECT`.